# How to use `getServerSideProps` in persistent layouts shared by multiple pages in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I have shared layouts for several logical groups of pages, for example:

- `DashboardLayout`:

  - `/dashboard/foo`
  - `/dashboard/bar`
- `UserLayout`:

  - `/user/settings`
  - `/user/profile`

Both `DashboardLayout` and `UserLayout` use data that has to be fetched on the server-side (e.g. from a database server).

How can I:

- fetch this data from the layout components when `getServerSideProps` only works in page components; and
- keep the fetching logic tied to the layouts and not the page components or the `App` component; and
- keep the layouts [persistent](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/) ([Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts)), i.e. prevent re-fetching/re-rendering when navigating between pages using the same layout (e.g. from `/user/settings` to `/user/profile`); and
- ideally not use any third-party libraries nor [shallow routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing)?

Comment: You could just pass some props from the page to the component no?